# Hot network question filter?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

Is there any chance that the powers that be could give us the option to select which networks we would like to see 'Hot Questions' from on the right-hand side of the page?

I'm aware of the Hot Network Questions -> Filtered Questions thing, I'm talking about the stuff that shows up by default:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84389/filtering-hot-questions http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90885/can-you-filter-out-certain-se-sites-from-the-hot-questions-list - it has been asked several times on MSE.

Comment: It got moved from the drop down *to* the right hand side of the page.  It is largely the same thing (now with random ordering!).  The filtering of hot questions still the same issue as it was when it was in the drop down.

Comment: To be totally up-front, this probably can't be done at in the very near future, but to clarify:  **Are you looking to indicate what sites you do like, or what sites you don't like?**  (I realize one interface could address both; I'm asking to better understand what's most important or not working for you today.)

Comment: @Jaydles: Sure, I realise it's not a five minute fix - no problem there. I don't have an issue with the operation as such, I'd just like to have the option to be spared from the notifications from networks that I couldn't care less about.

Comment: @MichaelT: My apologies for coming across as rude in my previous response, I didn't realise that's how it used to appear. No offence intended.

Comment: @TheBlueDog no problem.  Sometimes ferreting out the history of the site from meta can be a bit difficult... especially when other things change along with it over time.

Comment: @TheBlueDog, so, it sounds like for your individual case, it'd be more of a "don't show me this site" vs. "more of this site, please".

Comment: @Jaydles: That's pretty much the way I would envisage it, I'm just not sure about the other 99.9% of the community though - I'm a very small fish in a very big pond! However, if it gives you guys some food for thought ... ;)

Comment: I would *really* like to be able to turn off Hot Network Questions completely.  I constantly find myself lured into clicking one when I should be focusing on my work! On a weekend when browsing for fun, they are great.  During the week when I'm trying to work, they actually become a problem.

Comment: @MarkMeuer: Turning it off completely is easy enough if you use Adblock/Adblock Edge, just add `stackoverflow.com###hot-network-questions` to your custom filters.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Thanks!  Worked like a charm.  (Once I saw the [now-obvious] idea, I just added it do the filter interactively.)