# Is it possible to filter the 'Hot Network Posts' tab?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, filtering, hot-questions, sidebar

I see a tab on the right side of Stack Overflow's webpage (this is just a cutout):

[image]

There are a lot of top question of websites shown here. But, many of those do not interest me. I am mainly interested by [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/), [UNIX SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and sometimes even by [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Most of the other questions I see do not look interesting to me. I always (and even now) think that the use of this column is to promote other sites in the network. But posting questions of sites in which the user is not interested is of no use.

So is there a possible way of filtering the questions you see? If not, is it possible to do this with some script?

Also, working out things like this using scripts is usually messy, and if this isn't a feature, can this be created?

I have seen [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281862/allow-to-hide-a-hot-network-question) question, but I don't think that question is asking what I am.

Comment: There is a similar request on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225297/filter-hot-network-questions-by-excluding-sites) but that is status-deferred.

Comment: I've always been thinking that I want this to, but I'm to lazy to write a meta post about it.

Comment: I guess if your interests are limited enough that you don't occasionally want to see stuff outside your "comfort zone" this makes sense.  Personally I find it interesting to see what other people are looking at, _especially_ outside my areas of expertise.

Comment: I personally would be delighted if I never had to see questions about Gandalf or R2D2 ever again. And questions like "is it against our religion to eat a lollipop whilst riding a unicycle on thursdays?"

Comment: I can't confirm this, but I believe the more you visit a site the more likely it is that questions will show up in your hot network list. In saying that, a site you aren't interested in will likely still show up if the question is +50 etc

Comment: @Tas I wish that was the case, but AFAIK, the list is not currently personalized in any way.

Comment: I guess I'm the minority here. I enjoy viewing almost all Hot Network Questions, with the exception of religious based ones.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297280/18356 or http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272757/18356 on MSO, or [this MSE question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84389/134584).

Comment: @shoover: well my question isn't a duplicate of those. **(Link 1):** This is very close to my question. It nearly asks the same thing. But, even the answer provided is not solving the question. It is just giving an opinion of how it should look. And the question isn't exactly the same. **(Link 2):** I agree that the question is asking the same thing, but as there are no answers or solutions, it can't be a duplicate. If there would be a solution, it is a duplicate. **(Link 3):** It is asking the same thing, but does not have a solution, as the answers are using scripts. I don't want them.

Comment: In the entire SE universe, the solution to "there's a question that asks the same thing that I want to ask, but it doesn't have any answers" isn't "so I'll create a new question that asks the exact same thing". Vote up the other question, and edit it or do something with it to bump it up in visibility.